# Animation of a diagram with the package Smartdiagram

Tags: beamer, smartdiagram

I use `smartdiagram` to create a circular diagram with automatic animation.  I want to use it for a beamer presentation.
I want to show some introducing words on the top of the slide before starting the animation of the smartdiagram. My problem is that the smartdiagram always starts at the same time with the demonstration of the slide and not after the introduction. Like in my example the animation of the first module of the smartdiagram should start with keyword 1, then module two with keyword 2 and module 3 with keyword 3. I try to handle it with `\pause` but I didn't manage it.  Maybe you can help me.

Many thanks for your efforts!

**Example Code:**

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
 \frametitle{frametitle}
  a few introducing remarks ...\\[0.3cm] 
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr.5\linewidth-1em\relax}
  \begin{enumerate}[<+->]
    \setlength{\itemsep}{16pt}
    \item keyword 1
    \item keyword 2
    \item keyword 3
  \end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr.5\linewidth-1em\relax}
\begin{center}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric} % required in the preamble
\smartdiagramset{module shape = ellipse,
 arrow style = <-stealth,
font=\scriptsize,
module minimum width=0.8cm,
module minimum height=0.6cm,
text width=1.5cm,
circular distance=1.8cm,
}
\smartdiagramanimated[circular diagram:clockwise]{one,two,three}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 1):

If I use your Minimal Working Example and put a `\pause` between the "remarks" and `\begin{minipage}` it works as you want.
Furthermore, it is better to move `\usetikzlibrary` in the preamble, near `\usepackage`.

Comment: No, this doesn't really solve the problem; just adding that `\pause` makes slide 2 to have the first keyword (this is right) but modules one *and* two of the diagram, which is not the desired behaviour.

Comment: I misunderstood the question. I'm searching for a solution with doesn't involve rewriting of `smartdiagram`.

Answer (score 0):

You could acheive a similar effect to the one desired by simply wrapping diagram elements in `\only<>{}`. It's a slightly different effect than the one produced by `\smartdiagramanimated`, but quite striking as well. Working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric} % required in the preamble

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
 \frametitle{frametitle}
  a few introducing remarks ...\\[0.3cm] 
  \pause
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr.5\linewidth-1em\relax}
  \begin{enumerate}[<+->]
    \setlength{\itemsep}{16pt}
    \item keyword 1
    \item keyword 2
    \item keyword 3
  \end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr.5\linewidth-1em\relax}
\begin{center}
\smartdiagramset{module shape = ellipse,
 arrow style = <-stealth,
font=\scriptsize,
module minimum width=0.8cm,
module minimum height=0.6cm,
text width=1.5cm,
circular distance=1.8cm,
}
\smartdiagram[circular diagram:clockwise]{\only<2->{one},\only<3->{two},\only<4->{three}}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```